# Can't print an integer that has been converted to a string

Tags: string, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to do something that should be very simple. I am a bit frustrated for why my code won't work, so any help is appreciated :).

My program reads in data, and then makes a dictionary that records the number of times a particular item occurs (I am using Twitter data and counting hashtag occurrences). I want to output the top tweets, and have found a nice easy way to do that using the following:

```
def main():
    tweet_file = open(sys.argv[1])
    tweet_dic = lines(tweet_file) #function that makes my dictionary
    for i in range(0,10):
        big_key = max(tweet_dic, key = lambda i: tweet_dic[i])
        big_value = tweet_dic[big_key]
        sys.stdout = big_key + " " + str(big_value)
        del tweet_dic["big_key"]
    tweet_file.close()
```

The error I get on using this is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'`

Now I have outputted the two different values into terminal using `print` just fine, they can be put in two different `print` statements with no problems since I don't have to concatenate or anything. I have checked the two variables types, and as expected they are always `str` & `int`.

My understanding of the `str`(integer to convert) function is that you should be able to pass in an integer and get a string representation back! After it has been converted, I have been able to print out things like this in the past with no issues.

Things to consider that may be throwing it out - the `big_key` can sometimes be a `string` that was converted from Unicode by `.encode('utf-8')`. Otherwise the output from my file (printing on separate lines) looks like:

```
MTVHottest 60

KCAMexico 38

EXO 26

CD9 24

Unicode 19

Coders 18

AlonsoVillapandoTrendy 17

Unicode 14

Unicode 14
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just trying to print it to console? Any reason you are not simply doing : `print( big_key + " " + str(big_value))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is because of this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout

> stdout and stderr needn’t be built-in file objects: any object is acceptable as long as it has a write() method that takes a string argument.

stdout and stderr are the locations where the data is written, you aren't supposed to assign data itself to stdout, which is what it looks like you're doing.

As others have mentioned you would assign stdout to where you want and then use the print command to actually get the data to go there. But if all you're trying to do is print a line of text to a file then why not just open the file and write to it normally?

```
with open(tweet_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(big_key + " " + str(big_value))
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked. I didn't even want to use this method as I was very unfamiliar with stdout, but it had been recommended so I gave it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you're getting is from the line:

```
sys.stdout = big_key + " " + str(big_value)
```

This is not how things are output to *stdout*.

Using a `print` would be the appropriate way to do that:

```
print(big_key + " " + str(big_value))
```

There are some other strange things in your code example, like for example using `big_key` and then `"big_key"` in quotes. So probably that's not the end of your bugs and errors.

Comment: That would be a typing error hah. That isn't shared with my code. Thanks for pointing it out thought!